# Activate conda env within running Docker container?

Tags: python, docker, anaconda, containers, environment

Is there a way to spin up a Docker container and then activate a given conda environment within the container using a Python script? I don't have access to the Dockerfile of the image I'm using.

Comment: Yes. What do you do after activating the env? Are you logging into the container, or let it run some specific programs? The command would differ by your situation.

Comment: I need to create a container, run the container, activate the conda env within the container, and then run a python command that relies on the conda env.

Comment: Can you try: `docker run <image name> "conda activate <env name> && python <script name>"` or something like `docker run <image name> /opt/miniconda3/envs/<env name>/bin/python <script name>`, where "/opt/miniconda3" should be replaced with the path to the conda software inside the container.

Comment: I get an error response from docker for both of those commands "no such file or directory: unknown"

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing the file structure inside your image.  I would check if the file paths you typed in are correct.

Answer (score 0):

### conda run

Conda includes a `conda run` command for running arbitrary commands within an environment.

```bash
docker run <image> "conda run -n <your_env> python <script.py>"
```

If the script requires interaction, you may need the `--live-stream` and/or `--no-capture-output` arguments (see `conda run -h`).

Answer (score 0):

I think if you load right docker image there is no need to activate conda in your dockerfile try this image below

FROM continuumio/miniconda3

RUN conda info

This worked for me.